# Is $\arctan n$ always equal to $\arccos\sqrt{\frac{1}{n^2+1}}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry

$$\arccos\sqrt\frac{1}{2}=\arctan 1$$
$$\arccos\sqrt\frac{1}{5}=\arctan 2$$
$$\arccos\sqrt\frac{1}{10}=\arctan 3$$
$$\arccos\sqrt\frac{1}{17}=\arctan 4$$
$$\arccos\sqrt\frac{1}{26}=\arctan 5$$
$$\arccos\sqrt\frac{1}{37}=\arctan 6$$
$$\arccos\sqrt\frac{1}{50}=\arctan 7$$

The answer is a sequence $n^2+1$ for the slope which is in the inverse of tangent. Digits that are whole numbers. Is there any explanation as to why this is true? Is it a well-known problem?

Comment: Just draw a right angled triangle with adjacent side 1 and opposite side n. What do you observe about the hypotenuse?

Comment: well it's a square root of (n^2+1)

Answer (score 2):

$\arccos \sqrt \frac 1 n = x$ means $cos x = \frac 1 n$ which means $\sin x = \sqrt{1 - {\sqrt \frac 1 n}^2} = \sqrt{1 - \frac 1 n}$ so $\tan x = \frac{ \sqrt{1 - \frac 1 n}}{\sqrt \frac 1 n} = \sqrt{n - 1}$ so $\arctan{n -1} = x = \arccos \sqrt \frac 1 n$.  So this is known.

====

Another way of looking at it is:

$\tan = \frac {\sin}{\cos} $ and $\sin^2 + \cos^2 = 1$, so $\tan = \frac {\sqrt{1 - \cos^2}}{\cos} = \sqrt {\frac 1{\cos^2} - 1}$ so if $n = \cos x$ then $\tan =\sqrt {\frac 1{n^2} - 1}$

Comment: "It is known" (channelling Game of Thrones)

Comment: It's actually not known.  I didn't know it.  But as sin^ + cos^ 1 and tan = sin/cos, it wasn't particularly surprising.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\arctan n = a$, then $\tan(a)=n$ and...

$$1 + \tan^2 (a) = 1/(\cos^2 (a) )$$

$$1 + n^2 = 1/ (\cos^2 (a))$$

$$\cos^2 (a) = 1/(1+n^2)$$

$$\cos(a) = (1/(1+n^2) )^{1/2}$$

$$\arccos (1/(1+n^2) )^{1/2}   = a = \arctan(n)$$

Comment: I'm confused, sorry.Can you use the right math tools?

Answer (score 0):

if x=arccos y, than cos x = y, than sin x =sqrt(1-sqr(y)), than tan x = sqrt(1/y² - 1), than x=arctan(1/y² -1);
now set y=sqrt(1/(n²+1)  -> 1/sqr(y) -1 = (n²+1) - 1 = n² , and you have it!

The formula is valid not only for whole numbers, and the functions arctan and arccos has not only one value (only for the result where sin is positive the formula is valid)